# If neutron would be lighter by 1 MeV, how stability of Hydrogen could be changed?

Tags: standard-model, fine-tuning, proton-decay

In current Universe proton is stable and the following reaction does not go

$ p + e \rightarrow n + \overline{\nu_e}$

Currently proton is lighter than neutron by 1.293 MeV. If neutron would be lighter by 1 MeV, the difference would be lesser, then the mass of electron of 0.511 MeV.

Does this guarantee, that proton would decay by the formula above?

What could protect proton from decay then?

Comment: Robert N. Cahn: "The 18 Arbitrary Parameters Of The Standard Model In Your Everyday Life":http://www.radford.edu/~brockway/18_parameters.pdf

Comment: Presumably you meant the *decay* reaction $p \to n + \bar{e} + \nu_e$? (Note also electron capture would be $p + e \to n + \nu_e$.)